# previewmousewheel not getting raised when mouse is not on the control in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a combobox control's previewmousewheel event been handled. When my mouse is on the control and i move the center wheel of my mouse then this event gets raised. But when my mouse is away from the control and i move the center wheel of my mouse then this event does not get raised.

Can anybody please explain me why is this happening?

If I want to raise an event when my mouse is away from the control then which event should I handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

If the mouse cursor is not positioned over the control then no mouse events are routed through it. You wouldn't expect a mouse click event to be routed through it if the cursor was over a different control would you?

If you want this behaviour then I would suggest that you handle the mousewheel event in the page/view and route it from there, be cautious though as user expectation is for mouse and keyboard events to be handled by the in focus item.

Comment: thanks for the info. Well i thought that if the control contains focus then, irrespective of the position of the mouse, the wheel event should get raised. I am saying this because the data does gets rolled. Well i wrong in this case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In those cases that the user would expect the event to be forwarded to the control you could use `Mouse.Capture(someControl)` and `Mouse.Capture(null)` to stop the forwarding.

You should only use this when it makes sense. E.g. when dragging a scrollbar, when you started to drag on the thumb but are not required to stay on top of it as long as you keep the left mouse button down.

When using `Mouse.Capture()` make sure you always provide a way back from capturing.